# OpenGL SDK on Windows

Tags: windows, opengl, sdk

I'm trying to write an OpenGL application so I installed the Windows 7 SDK.
However, it appears that it is OpenGL 1.1...

```
#define GL_VERSION_1_1                    1
```

How can I find which version of OpenGL I have installed(*.dll) and where can I find the newer *.lib/*.h files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft hasn't updated their OpenGL headers/libraries for quite a while. To use newer features, you normally want to use [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLEE](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/).

Comment: GLEE only handles extensions up to OpenGL 3.0, its better to use GLEW these days.

Comment: @bobobobo: Undoubtedly true *if* you really care about OpenGL 3.1 or 4.0. OTOH, keep in mind that most of what happened in the move from 3.0 to 3.1 wasn't adding extensions, but removing outdated features. For many people, the fact that GLEE handles its initialization automatically probably means more.

Comment: Downloads are broken on the GLEE website. :(

Comment: GLEW is not available either. :(

Comment: @Calmarius: I just did a quick check -- latest version that supports up through GL 4.3 downloaded just fine.

Answer (score 3):

There is no new version of OpenGL in Win7. You must download new headers form opengl.org and use extension techniques of OpenGL to obtain advanced functionality. For version of OpenGL use this function [glGetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd373553(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: You can use glGetString only after initialize OpenGL context. If there is no context in you program it's always error to use anyone other Ope nGL functions.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own OpenGL extension loader (like GLEE or GLEW) because I didn't like the licenses for the other available libraries.  I don't think anyone should ever have to do this again, so I've made mine public domain, do with it as you will. I'd like to hear if you use it in something, but that's not a requirement.  It supports up to OpenGL 4.1 at the moment.

http://www.onemanmmo.com/index.php?cmd=newsitem&comment=news.1.28.0

Comment: The license for GLEW and GLEE are both MIT-style permissive. This is functionally no different from public domain. Indeed legally, MIT-style may be more suitable for wider use, as the definition of public domain can be different in different places, while copyright licensing is generally works the same way.

Comment: MIT license is good, but it requires you to put a notice in the product's documentation.  I don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NVIDIA graphics, download NVIDIA OpenGL SDK. You get the latest compliant with OpenGL 4.4.

First demo application is available from:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd369065%28v=vs.85%29.aspx