# MSVC OpenGL version 1.2 where to find?

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I need to set a "clamp-to-edge" wrap param mode to my texture:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

in my Microsoft Visual Studio C++ application targeting Win32 platform.

This does not work:

error C2065: 'GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE' : undeclared identifier

I understand the reason: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\PlatformSDK" contains OpenGL version 1.1 whereas `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` was introduced in the version 1.2.

I tried to define it as

```
#define GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE 0x812F
```

but it had no effect.

So, I need to link against a newer (at least version 1.2) OpenGL library for Windows. My question is: where can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get access to OpenGL 1.2 or greater, you need to use the extension loading mechanism. I suggest you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272831/opengl-sdk-on-windows) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309615/how-do-i-use-the-latest-opengl), or tl:dr, look at [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) or [GLEE](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/libs/GLee/). These automatically load OpenGL extensions at runtime to allow you to use modern OpenGL functionality.