# GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE not available

Tags: opengl

I've heard that `GL_CLAMP` is deprecated, but it seems like I don't have access to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`, which should be used instead. I can only use `GL_CLAMP`. I'm using Visual Studio 2012. How can I fix this?

I've checked my OpenGL version, and it's 3.1.0:

```
3.1.0 - Build 8.15.10.2418
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272831/opengl-sdk-on-windows)

> Microsoft hasn't updated their OpenGL headers/libraries for quite a
>   while. To use newer features, you normally want to use GLEW or GLEE.

And [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492035/msvc-opengl-version-1-2-where-to-find)

> To get access to OpenGL 1.2 or greater, you need to use the extension
>   loading mechanism. I suggest you look ... look at GLEW or GLEE.

GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE was introduced in version OpenGL 1.2